# Error in installing redmon on windows 7?

Tags: redmon

i installed redmon(without defining any virtual printer to use Redirect ports) and uninstalled it,but when i installed the program again,it gives me this error:error copying help file,Error = 5 Access is denied

i even use a uninstaller app like ***Advanced Uninstaller PRO 12*** to delete software but it gives me again that error.

Comment: is there another solution ...for example have a software that works like redmon?

Answer (score 0):

i found the solution,i go to regitery Editor[by writting regedit in run]
after that i search 'red' text in it,i found the regisitry Associated with redmon,i found that some files in system32  associate with this registery,i delete redmon files in system32  directory and delete that registery... and the the problem solved.